# Adding a row to a TableLayoutPanel in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am currently developing an application in C# using Windows Forms.

I am using a TableLayoutPanel with two columns. How do I add a new row programatically to the table. I have tried doing a google search, but the only problem is I am only finding adding a new row style which doesn't seem right to me.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope that's correct. If you want to add a row you need to use  [`RowStyles.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160572.aspx).

One easy way of checking this for you self of course is to look at the Form.Designer.cs code.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I was thinking adding row styles was more to do with the row colours or fonts more than an actual row. Thanks for the help.